# How can `UICollectionViewLayout` access data for invisible cells?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I'd like to fetch all data from a data source — both for visible *and* invisible cells — in order to calculate attributes for visible cells. `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:` doesn't work because it returns `nil` for invisible cells. As stated in the [UICollectionView API](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UICollectionView/cellForItemAtIndexPath:):

> **Return Value**
>
> The cell object at the corresponding index path or `nil` if the cell is not visible or *indexPath* is out of range.

Any ideas on how I can fetch the underlying data without breaking MVC constraints (e.g., storing a reference to the data in the layout)?

Comment: Perhaps you might expand on the problem? From the perspective of the layout, in the prepareLayout method, can you not query the collectionView.dataSource  for numberOfSections /numberOfItemsInSection and apply  UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes accordingly?

Comment: Yes, I can access the number of sections and items per section. But I'm trying to access the contents of non-visible cells because their contents affect the frame of visible cells.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main problem I'm facing is that I need information from the underlying data source to set up attributes of visible and non-visible cells, as well as supplementary views. The `UICollectionViewDelegate` protocol requires that cells are dequeued *after* the layout attributes have already been set, even though the implementing class (usually the `UICollectionViewController` has access to the data source).

The [Collection View Programming Guide hints](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/CreatingCellsandViews/CreatingCellsandViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012334-CH7-SW1) that the delegate object can extended to provide additional information. Using the `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` as a [reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout/collectionView%3alayout%3asizeForItemAtIndexPath%3a), I created a new protocol that declares the methods for the data I needed. My `UICollectionViewController` subclass then conformed to that protocol by implemented those methods, without any layout operations (like dequeuing view cells).

My protocol looks something like this:

```
@protocol MyCollectionViewDelegateLayout <UICollectionViewDelegate>
- (CGSize)sizeForCellAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
- (CGSize)sizeForHeaderAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
@end
```

My collection view controller then has the following structure:

```
@interface MyCollectionViewController : UICollectionViewController
    <MyCollectionViewDelegateLayout>
...
@end

@implementation MyCollectionViewController
...
- (CGSize)sizeForCellAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Make calculations based on data at index path.
    return CGSizeMake(width, height);
}
- (CGSize)sizeForHeaderAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    // Make calculations based on data at index path.
    return CGSizeMake(width, height);
}
```

Inside the `prepareLayout` method in my `UICollectionViewLayout` subclass, I call these methods to pre-calculate the necessary attributes:

```
@implementation MyCollectionViewLayout
...
- (void)prepareLayout
{
    ...
    // Iterate over sections and rows...
    id dataSource = self.collectionView.dataSource;
    if ([dataSource respondsToSelector:@selector(sizeForCellAtIndexPath:)]) {
        CGSize size = [dataSource sizeForCellAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    } else {
        // Use default values or calculate size another way
    }
    ...
}
...
```

Using an extended data source protocol allows the code to maintain MVC Separation of Concerns. Here, the layout class still doesn't know anything about the underlying data, but is able to use it to define attributes. Conversely, the controller class does not lay anything out, instead only providing sizing hints based on the underlying data.